# How to remove duplicated rows and columns from a data frame disregarding NAs?

Tags: r

I would like to remove duplicated columns from a data frame, disregarding NAs. All columns of the data frame are numeric vectors with equal length. Here is an example:

```
> df <- data.frame(a = c(1,2,NA,4,4), b= c(5,6,7,8,8), c= c(5,6,7,8,8), d = c(9,8,7,6,NA), e = c(NA,8,7,6,6))
> df
   a b c  d  e
1  1 5 5  9 NA
2  2 6 6  8  8
3 NA 7 7  7  7
4  4 8 8  6  6
5  4 8 8 NA  6
```

I would like to get this data frame as a result:

```
> df_clear
   a b d
1  1 5 9
2  2 6 8
3 NA 7 7
4  4 8 6
```

I have tried "unique”, but without any success. Only duplicates without NAs were removed.

```
> df_clear <- 
+   df %>%
+     unique %>%
+     t %>%
+     as.matrix %>%
+     unique %>%
+     t %>%
+     as.data.frame
> df_clear
   a b  d  e
1  1 5  9 NA
2  2 6  8  8
3 NA 7  7  7
4  4 8  6  6
5  4 8 NA  6
```

"distinct" from dplyr didn't help either. I even lost the column names with this approach which is a problem.

```
> df_clear <- 
+   df %>%
+     distinct %>%
+     t %>%
+     as.data.frame %>%
+     distinct %>%
+     t %>%
+     as.data.frame
> df_clear
   V1 V2 V3 V4
V1  1  5  9 NA
V2  2  6  8  8
V3 NA  7  7  7
V4  4  8  6  6
V5  4  8 NA  6
```

I wonder if there is any function that does the job or I should write it for myself. The real data frame has over 1000 rows and columns.

Thanks a lot for your help!

EDIT

After reading the comments I realized that I under-defined the original question. Here are some clarification. For the sake of simplicity I focus on rows only:
- In case of duplicates the remaining row should contain as few NAs as possible. E.g. df1 should appear as df1_clear

```
> df1
   a b  d e
1  1 4  7 1
2  3 6 NA 3
3  2 5  8 2
4 NA 6  9 3
> df1_clear
  a b d e
1 1 4 7 1
2 2 5 8 2
3 3 6 9 3
```

- The duplicates are not necessarily consecutive.
- There could be more than one NA in a row.

Comment: It's not clear to me that the output you are asking for is well defined. Why is row 5 dropped and column d included in the result, instead of dropping row 1 and including column e?

Comment: Thanks for the question. I've edited the original post to clarify this point.

Comment: Your edits introduced an apparently desired merging of records, which complexifies what you're trying to do. It's still not clear to me what exactly the desired output is. For instance, given `df <- data.frame(a=c(1,2,NA,NA), b=c(NA,NA,4,5),c=c(9,9,9,9))`, what would `df_clear` look like? How would you fill in NAs from otherwise matching rows, if there are multiple options?

Comment: I haven’t thought of that either, thanks a lot for your question! In this case I would not merge either row. I also realized that the merging order of rows and columns (i.e. rows first or columns first) could lead to different results in some cases. I would not expect such ambiguity for my data, but I could never know. So following your question, first I will check if such ambiguity is present. If yes, I’ll look into those rows and columns separately and try to find an explanation and merge the specific rows and columns accordingly. Than, I’ll do the merging for the whole data set.

Answer (score 5):

The following is a bit complicated but it does the job.
It calls a function within `fun` twice, to remove the duplicates of the original dataframe, then of its transpose.

```
fun <- function(DF){
  f <- function(DF1){
    df1 <- DF1
    df1[] <- lapply(df1, function(x){
      y <- zoo::na.locf(x)
      if(length(y) < length(x)) y <- zoo::na.locf(x, fromLast = TRUE)
      y
    })
    DF1[!duplicated(df1), ]
  }
  df2 <- f(DF)
  df2 <- as.data.frame(t(df2))
  df2 <- t(f(df2))
  as.data.frame(df2)
}

fun(df)
#   a b d
#1  1 5 9
#2  2 6 8
#3 NA 7 7
#4  4 8 6
```

Based on the above, it is possible to do it with the function `f()` in `fun` and `dplyr` pipes. Function `f()` below is just a copy&paste of the function above.

```
library(dplyr)


f <- function(DF1){
  df1 <- DF1
  df1[] <- lapply(df1, function(x){
    y <- zoo::na.locf(x)
    if(length(y) < length(x)) y <- zoo::na.locf(x, fromLast = TRUE)
    y
  })
  DF1[!duplicated(df1), ]
}


df %>%
  f() %>% t() %>% as.data.frame() %>%
  f() %>% t() %>% as.data.frame()

#   a b d
#1  1 5 9
#2  2 6 8
#3 NA 7 7
#4  4 8 6
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! As I understood it works only for consecutive rows/columns. I failed to specify in the original post that the duplicates are not necessarily consecutive.